# Filter Pandas Dataframe Columns by header containing multiple strings

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and want to only show columns with headers containing a  particular string(s).

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains(['BB','TP'])]
```

So this would only show columns that contain BB or TP. This doesn't work for 2 conditions however.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Good idea, that works

Comment: df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('|'.join('BB','TP')]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
L = ['BB','TP']
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(L)]
```